# Strange integers in c language

Tags: c, int, declaration

I have code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a = sum(1, 3);

  return 0;
}

int sum(int a, int b, int c) {
  printf("%d\n", c);

  return a + b + c;
}
```

I know that I have to declare functions first, and only after that I can call them, but I want to understand what happends.

(Compiled by `gcc v6.3.0`)

I ignored `implicit declaration of function warning` and ran program several times, output was this:

```
1839551928
-2135227064
41523672
// And more strange numbers
```

I have 2 questions:

1) What do these numbers mean?

2) How function `main` knows how to call function `sum` without it declaration?

Comment: What about the fact that you define `int sum(int a, int b, int c)` but call it as `sum(1, 3)` (_i.e._ with less arguments than there are parameters)? Is it intentional?

Comment: (1) Nothing (2) It doesn’t, which is why everything breaks. Allowed for historical reasons. but your compiler probably yelled at you, which you need to pay attention to in C and treat as an error.

Comment: See [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: I read that if compiler doesnt know function's siganture it cant generate errors, thats why i wanted to see what will happend with missed parameters.

Comment: I just compiled your program with gcc 6.3.0 and got a warning: "warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sum’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]". You should have gotten the same warning, and if you did get it, you should have quoted it in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that the code in your question is the code you're actually compiling and running:

```
int main() {
  int a = sum(1, 3);

  return 0;
}

int sum(int a, int b, int c) {
  printf("%d\n", c);

  return a + b + c;
}
```

The call to `printf` is invalid, since you don't have the required `#include <stdio.h>`. But that's not what you're asking about, so we'll ignore it. *The question was edited to add the include directive.*

In standard C, since the 1999 standard, calling a function (`sum` in this case) with no visible declaration is a *constraint violation*. That means that a diagnostic is required (but a conforming compiler can still successfully compile the program if it chooses to). Along with syntax errors, constraint violations are the closest C comes to saying that something is illegal. (Except for `#error` directives, which must cause a translation unit to be rejected.)

Prior to C99, C had an "implicit `int`" rule, which meant that if you call a function with no visible declaration an implicit declaration would be created. That declaration would be for a function with a return type of `int`, and with parameters of the (promoted) types of the arguments you passed. Your call `sum(1, 3)` would create an implicit declaration `int sum(int, int)`, and generate a call *as if* the function were defined that way.

Since it isn't defined that way, the behavior is undefined. (Most likely the value of one of the parameters, perhaps the third, will be taken from some arbitrary register or memory location, but the standard says *nothing* about what the call will actually do.)

C99 (the 1999 edition of the ISO C standard) dropped the implicit `int` rule. If you compile your code with a conforming C99 or later compiler, the compiler is required to diagnose an error for the `sum(1, 3)` call. Many compilers, for backward compatibility with old code, will print a non-fatal warning and generate code that *assumes* the definition matches the implicit declaration. And many compilers are non-conforming by default, and might not even issue a warning. (BTW, if your compiler did print an error or warning message, it is tremendously helpful if you include it in your question.)

Your program is buggy. A conforming C compiler must at least warn you about it, and possibly reject it. If you run it in spite of the warning, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Yes, I forgot add #include <stdio.h> in question and you're right that I compiled this code.

Answer (score 1):

This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) per [**6.5.2.2 Function calls**, paragraph 9 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p9):

> If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is undefined.

Functions without prototypes are allowed under [**6.5.2.2 Function calls**, paragraph 6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6):

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument promotions. If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined. ...

Note again: if the parameters passed don't match the arguments expected, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Well, thanks. I just quoted the standard. You explained better what's going on.  That can get you downvotes from some posters here when undefined behavior is being discussed - that's what probably got the OP the current downvote:  "Bah, it's just undefined behavior and not worthy of investigation or reasoning!"  Of course, that's not very helpful to anyone new to C who doesn't understand what undefined behavior is.

Comment: Your answer is correct for C90, but incorrect for C99 and later. It's not merely undefined behavior. As of C99 or later, the call `sum(1, 3)` is a constraint violation, since the "implicit `int`" rule was dropped. A diagnostic message is required. (That can be a non-fatal warning -- which is IMHO unfortunate.) It's still legal to call a function without a visible *prototype*, but it's invalid to call a function without an explicit *declaration*, as the OP's program does. See my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson If it's a constraint violation (and 6.5.2.2p2 almost made me post that the code is a constraint violation...), that doesn't explain wording such as "For a call to a function without a function prototype in scope where the function is not defined with a function prototype" in [**J.2 Undefined behavior**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2). That wording is at best inconsistent with a lack of a prototype being a constraint violation. There's a series of UB definitions similar to that one. A constraint violation wouldn't require it to be defined as UB, would it?

Comment: A *prototype* is a *function declaration* that specifies the types of the parameters. Calling a function with no visible *declaration* is allowed in C90, but is a constraint violation in C99 and later. Calling a function with no visible *prototype* is valid in all versions of C, but a declaration is still required in C99 and later.

Answer (score 1):

In strictly standard conforming C, if you don't declare a function before using it, it will assume certain default argument types for the function.This is based on early versions of C with a weaker type system, and retained only for backwards compatibility. It should not be used generally.
 Ill skip the details here, but in your case it assumes sum takes 2 ints and returns an int.

Calling a function with the wrong number of parameters, as you are doing here, is undefined behaviour.  When you call sum, the compiler thinks that it takes two integers, so it passes two integers to it. When the function is actually called, however, it tries to read one more integer, `c`. Since you only passed 2 ints, the space for `c` contains random crap, which is what you're seeing when you print out. Note that it doesn't have to do this, since this is undefined behaviour, it could do anything. It could have given values for b & c, for example.

Obviously this behaviour is confusing, and you should not rely on undefined behaviour, so you'd be better off compiling with stricter compiler settings so this program wouldn't compile. (The proper version would declare sum above main.)

Comment: *it will assume that the function takes integers* Not really. It's not that simple.  The argument will undergo default argument promotions.

Comment: You're right,  I was trying to simplify but in this case I simplified to the point of being wrong. I'll edit.

Comment: @undefined7887 I upvoted, I thought it was a valid question

Comment: In standard C since the 1999 standard, calling a function with no visible declaration is as constraint violation (the closest C comes to saying "illegal"). The default argument and return type assumptions applied only in the 1990 version of the language. Many compiler still implement the older semantics for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

1) Since you haven't provided value for parameter "c" when calling function "sum" its value inside the function is undefined. If you declared function before main, your program wouldn't even compile, and you would get "error: too few arguments to function call" error.

2) Normally, it doesn't. Function has to be declared before the call so the compiler can check function signature. Compiler optimizations solved this for you in this case.

Comment: *Since you haven't provided value for parameter "c" when calling function "sum" its value inside the function is undefined.* Not necessarily.  Depending on the argument passing convention for the platform, `a` could very well be the parameter without a value assigned.  Or anything else - it's undefined behavior, and it's not really possible to characterize it, especially with optimizing compilers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if C works exactly like this but, your function calls work like a stack in memory. When you call a function your arguments are put on that stack so when in the fuction you can access them by selecting less x positions on memory. So:
You call  `summ(1, 3)`
the stack will have 1 and the on the top a 3.
when executing the fuction it will see the last position of memory for the 1º argument (it recovers the 1) and then the position before that for the 2º argument (recovering the 3), however, there is a 3º argument so it accesses the position before that as well.
This position is garbige as not put by you and different everytime you run it.

Hope it was clear enought. Remeber that the stack works is inverted so every time you add something it goes to the previous memory position, not the next.

Comment: This is not how C works. First of all, he's invoked undefined behaviour so anything can happen, and second, modern compilers usually pass the first 4 (or so) arguments of a function in registers.